# Mount Docker container folder (without copying) in host machine

Tags: c++, linux, docker, visual-studio-code, mount

My C++ development environment is *contained* in a Docker container that has a volume with my source folder (mounted from a folder in my Linux host machine).

I am using VS Code to code and the Docker container to compile and run my tests.

Since header files are placed in my container are not visible by VS Code extensions, I have thousand of issues due to missing headers.

I am wondering which is the best way to solve this issue.

Basically I am looking a way to mount container folders in my host machine (read-only mode should be enough) without copying.

I've tried something like this (as a simplified example), but it is copying all files instead of just mounting them:

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
    foo:
        image: alpine:latest
        volumes:
        - test:/etc
volumes:
    test:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: none
            o: bind
            device: /home/xxx/Temp/test
```

Comment: That sounds like you want to have the toolchain installed directly on the host, rather than having it isolated inside a container.  Can you use your OS package manager or a version-manager tool to install these packages directly on the host?  You cannot mount container directories to the host, and you cannot run binaries packaged in a Docker image without launching a container to do it.

Comment: I am not supposed to copy the toolchain on my laptop due to NDA and security restriction, furthermore it is a toolchain for embedded system, so it is tricky to be installed, because of that they decide to _encapsulate_ in a dock container.